# Placement of verb in a simple phrase

Tags: standard-german

Which is right:

"Die Lösung zu finden ist kompliziert.", or
"Die Lösung ist kompliziert zu finden."

And why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. It's a matter of emphasis.

Your examples focus on *Die Lösung*, then the element at the end.

> **Die Lösung** zu finden *ist kompliziert*.
>
> **Die Lösung** ist kompliziert *zu finden*.

This second example is the usual word order, with the subject in front and infinitives last.

Putting adverbs or actions in front makes them extra-emphasized:

> **Kompliziert** ist die Lösung *zu finden*.
>
> **Zu finden** ist die Lösung *kompliziert*.

The last one is unusual but also allowed:

> **Kompliziert** zu finden ist *die Lösung*.

The following one is wrong:

> <s>**Zu finden** kompliziert ist *die Lösung*.</s>

Comment: Gelungen ist zu geben eine gute Erklärung!

Comment: These sentences do not only differ in word order but also in their grammatical structure: In the first sentence *die Lösung* is accusative, but in the second it's nominative. One can see this when *Lösung* (female) is replaced by *Weg* (male): *Den Weg* zu finden ist kompliziert / *Der Weg* ist kompliziert zu finden.